# Problems creating the mute command for a disk bot written in Python

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )
async def mute(ctx,member:discord.Member,time:int,reason):
    muterole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,id=726429210012549121)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Мут',color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина',value=reason,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Время',value=time,inline=False)
    await member.add_roles(muterole)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(muterole)
```

Hello!  I created the mute command for my bot in the Python programming language  The code is correct,but unfortunately after the last two lines, the bot does not issue the Muted role  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )
async def mute(ctx,member:discord.Member,time,reason):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "(Your Muted Role Name"):
            """""""""
            Add role to member here
            time sleep(int(time))
            Remove role here
            """""
```

You have to check role name with if statement and then you have to do whatever you want.